# how to reference information on a webpage?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I have this web page : [link web page](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM)
I would like to cite it I have tried this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @misc{Hariharan,
  title  = {What are Kernels in Machine Learning and SVM?},
  author = {Hariharan, B. (n.d.).},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-
  Learning-and-SVM}",
  note   = {Accessed: 2017-04-15}
   }
  \end{filecontents}

 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \usepackage[hyphens]{url}

 \begin{document}
 \cite{Hariharan}
 \bibliography{mybib}
 \end{document}
```

I am supposed to get somthing like  this [image: figue]
But I get this 
`Hariharan, B. n. (n.d.). What are kernels in machine learning and
svm? https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine
-Learning-and-SVM. (Accessed: 2016-09-17)`
anyone can correct me!

Comment: Put the author in an extra pair of curly braces. Do you have to introduce that yellow background?

Comment: no (forgot for the yellow background soory)  I do this?   `@misc{{Bharath Hariharan},
  title  = {What are Kernels in Machine Learning and SVM?},
  author = {Hariharan, B. (n.d.).},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-
  Learning-and-SVM}",
  note   = {Accessed: 2017-04-15}
   }  Bharath Hariharan` I mean his full name !!

Comment: or this   `@misc{Bharath Hariharan, title = {What are Kernels in Machine Learning and SVM?}, author = {Bharath Hariharan}, howpublished = "\url{https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine- Learning-and-SVM}", note = {Accessed: 2017-04-15} } Bharath Hariharan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer was posted on 21 December 2013, I think it's a good idea to provide this information via explicit `year`, `month`, and `day` fields. Actually, the `@misc` entry type ignores the fields `month` and `day`; nevertheless, I think it's a good idea to record these pieces of information in the bibliographic entry.

In addition, do get rid of the (N.D.) in the `author field`. (You'll notice that I disagree here with the output shown in the screenshot you posted...) Be sure to encase the acronym "SVM" in curly braces to prevent BibTeX from converting it lowercase. Finally, I think that the `title` field should provide an indication that Hariharan's posting consists of an *answer* to a question, and not to the question itself.. In short, I'd write the entry as

```
@misc{hariharan:2013,
  author       = "Bharath Hariharan",
  title        = "Answer to `{What} are Kernels in Machine Learning and {SVM}?'",
  year         = "2013",
  month        = "December",
  day          = "21",
  url          = "https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM",
  urldate      = "2017-07-18",
}
```

Of course, this setup is based, in part, on knowledge that you use the `apacite` bibliography style.

Comment: defenitely gratefull :) thank you bu the way the fact I added this web pages to bibligraphy something strange appear I got every link in square  ( particularly green square) what could be wrong here knowing that it does not exist before adding web pages references!

Comment: @mirette - Did you load the `hyperref` package with the option `colorlinks`?  If you did not, that would certainly explain why the hyperlinks are indicated as colored rectangles. A word of general advice: You should really consider finding -- and consulting! -- the user guides of various LaTeX packages you use. You'll obtain a lot of very good answers there -- and you'll probably find them in the user guides much more quickly than if you post queries to the Internet...