# my references do appear strangely

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref

I have references (journal articles, conferences...) but I have added some web pages, sites etc. Once I do that like in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381112/how-to-reference-information-on-a-webpage) (and here I would like to thank who have helped me to do so correctly) I get something a bit strange that I did not have before. Each one of my references (even those which are not web pages) appear in squares. I am worried about that because I don't know ehether I get that on paper when I print my thesis document! Do they appear in impression? How to delete these green squares on my text and the blue on my page web references??
[image: here is the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the next time, please provide a working minimal example.

However, those boxes come from the hyperref package. Loading it as

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

should solve your problem.

And for the record: Those which are no hyperlinks are document-internal links, in this case from your citations to your reference list. That's why they have different colours.

Comment: the box has deseappear thank you but references have green color within my text :( and the web page on the references part has rose color how to make them black it is  a thesis am not permitted to put colors and thank you :)

Comment: Don't load hyperref.

Comment: You can just change the color of all kinds of links hyperref creates. In your case `\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}` should do the trick. For more information, the [hyperref documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is always there to help you out.

Comment: Or yes, follow Johannes_B suggestion, which will also work. But note that in this case you will loose most interactivity in your document.

Comment: on the part references it has been okey all in black but my text all referencess still green unfortunately :(  ( @Johannes_B I wonder in this case if my web pages maybee will not appear anymore !! or even if I delete it it would work !! ) ( soory am new and no experienced particularly with packages... ) I am using a template and I did not change the default packages

Comment: @Johannes_B it works thank you for the proposition :) thank you both of you Manel and Johannes :)

Comment: @mirette By the way, the boxes are just visible on screen, they won't be printed.